# Converting custom encoding to ascii

Tags: javascript, unicode, encoding, react-native

I have a string in the following form \u0000n \u0000u...... now when I try to display it in browser it shows nothing (Empty string). I found the reason for that using this http://r12a.github.io/apps/conversion/
it shows that \u0000n gets converted to \0n thus null character is encountered before the end of actual string.

My question is that I still want to print the string without the null character so is there any workaround to this or should I just trim the 0's after \u character.

Comment: display it as a string.

Comment: Tried didn't work still displays nothing!!!!

Comment: what do you mean with "print"? how do you try to display it?

Comment: In a terminal and on an emulator(android)

Comment: so you want "\u0000n \u0000u" to show up as "\u0000n \u0000u" and not "nu" right?

Comment: I want \u0000n \u0000u as nu but its returning ""